# Firebase and Vuex: Why does the user profile doc not exist until page refresh?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2, vuex

I got this sign up form that dispatches user sign up payload, creates user account with email/password, and then it will create a new user profile document for this user in firebase/fireStore for use throughout the app.

The **problem** is that for some reason the user profile is not "done" despite async/await being set on the 'fetchUser' , and because I am navigating to a 'dashboard' when the user profile is supposed to be available, I get an "document does not exist" error for the user profile. However, this does not happen all the time. If it does happen, all I have to do is refresh the page and the user profile will exist.

**Does anyone spot any errors in my flow ? Any tips?**

I am new to firebase and Vuex, and I am probably being over-indulgent with await, but better safe than sorry...

I've pasted my code below, but here is my console log steps, too:

[image]

> the sign up method:

```
    async signUp() {
      this.isLoading = true
      try {
        await this.$store.dispatch('signUserUp', {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.passOne
        })
        if (this.error) {
          this.errorMsg = this.error
        } else {
          await this.$store.dispatch('fetchUser')
          // sometimes form will briefly reappear , so this fixes that
          await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.$router.replace('dashboard', resolve, reject)
          })
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('error on signup page: ', err)
      }
    }
```

> the `signUserUp()` action in Vuex store:

```
      async signUserUp({ commit }, payload) {
        commit('SET_LOADING', true)
        // clear any errors out that may have been there previously
        commit('CLEAR_ERROR')
        const user = await this.$fireAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          payload.email,
          payload.password
        )
        try {
          // create user document; used for user profiles
          this.$fireStore.collection('users').doc(user.user.uid).set({
            displayName: this.$fireAuth.currentUser.displayName,
            username: this.$fireAuth.currentUser.email,
            email: payload.email,
            uid: this.$fireAuth.currentUser.uid,
            providerId: this.$fireAuth.currentUser.providerData[0].providerId,
            photoUrl: 'https://api.adorable.io/avatars/94/abott@adorable.png',
            createdAt: this.$fireStoreObj.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
          })
        } catch (error) {
          commit('SET_ERROR', error)
          console.log('register error', error)
        }
      },
```

> the `fetchUser()` in Vuex store:

```
      async fetchUser({ commit, dispatch }, authUser) {
        if (authUser) {
          console.log('user state is authenticated')
          commit('SET_CURRENT_USER', await authUser)
          console.log('got user?', authUser)
          await dispatch('fetchUserProfile')
          console.log('got userprofile from store')
        } else {
          console.log('user NOT authenticated')
          commit('SET_CURRENT_USER', null)
          commit('SET_USER_PROFILE', {})
        }
      }
```

Note: I am using NuxtJS and have a `onAuthStateChangedAction` in Vuex.

Comment: so, changing this line `this.$router.replace('dashboard', resolve, reject)` to `this.$router.push('/dashboard,  resolve, reject)` SEEMS to help. Haven't seen it fail yet.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work as good as I thought...back to drawing board...